# Jquery doesn't identify the class as a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have two Jquery functions where one will insert a new dynamic row to a form on a button click and other function will validate the cell in that row.

```
var currentItem = 11;
$('#addnew').click(function(){
  currentItem++;
  $('#items').val(currentItem);
  var strToAdd = '<tr><td><select class="form-control select2 productSelect" name="product'+currentItem+'" id="product'+currentItem+'" style="width: 100%"> <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>'+ <?php foreach ($productData as $product) { echo "'<option value=" . $product->product_id . ">" . $product->product_name . "</option>'+";}?> '</select> </td><td><input class="form-control quantitySelect" name="quantity'+currentItem+'" id ="quantity'+currentItem+'"type="text" /></td><td><input class="form-control"  name="freeIssue'+currentItem+'" id="freeIssue'+currentItem+'" type="text" /></td> <td align="center"><button  class="btn btn-danger" name="close" id="close" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td></tr>';

  $('#data').append(strToAdd);


});
```

Here I take the class name **productSelect** as the identifier for the second function to make validation. But it didn't recognize the class and  the validation is not working for the rows which I add to the form by the above function.

```
  $('.productSelect').change(function () {

  var elementID = $(this).attr("id");
  var numberPart = elementID.split("t", 2);

  if ($(this).val() != null ) {
    $('#quantity'+ numberPart[1]).prop('required',true);
  }
});
```

This is how the entire code looks like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.productSelect').change(function () {

  var elementID = $(this).attr("id");
  var numberPart = elementID.split("t", 2);

  if ($(this).val() != null ) {
    $('#quantity'+ numberPart[1]).prop('required',true);
  }
});

var currentItem = 11;
$('#addnew').click(function(){
  currentItem++;
  $('#items').val(currentItem);
  var strToAdd = '<tr><td><select class="form-control select2 productSelect" name="product'+currentItem+'" id="product'+currentItem+'" style="width: 100%"> <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>'+ <?php foreach ($productData as $product) { echo "'<option value=" . $product->product_id . ">" . $product->product_name . "</option>'+";}?> '</select> </td><td><input class="form-control quantitySelect" name="quantity'+currentItem+'" id ="quantity'+currentItem+'"type="text" /></td><td><input class="form-control"  name="freeIssue'+currentItem+'" id="freeIssue'+currentItem+'" type="text" /></td> <td align="center"><button  class="btn btn-danger" name="close" id="close" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td></tr>';

  $('#data').append(strToAdd);


});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Comment: @rv7 Yes sure now I have edited my post and inserted my full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $(document).on.('change', '.productSelect', function (){})
Because method couldn't found the class on document ready